# Make and incremental builds

Tags: c, makefile, environment

I was wondering ...

When you make a change to either `file1.c` or `file2.c` or `file1.h`, the following makefile recompiles only what's needed (which is nice)

```
# Link to executable
result: file1.o file2.o
    gcc file1.o file2.o -o result23

# Assemble to .o object files
file1.o:    file1.s
    gcc -c dist/file1.s

file2.o:    file2.s
    gcc -c dist/file2.s

# Compile to .s assembly files
file1.s:    file1.c
    gcc -S file1.c

file2.s:    file2.c
    gcc -S file2.c
```

When I move built object to another directory, however, everything is rebuilt at all times, regardless whether only 1 file's content was changed.

```
# Link to executable
result: file1.o file2.o
    gcc file1.o file2.o -o result23

# Assemble to .o object files
file1.o:    file1.s
    gcc -c dist/file1.s
    mv file1.o dist

file2.o:    file2.s
    gcc -c dist/file2.s
    mv file2.o dist

# Compile to .s assembly files
file1.s:    file1.c
    gcc -S file1.c
    mv file1.s dist

file2.s:    file2.c
    gcc -S file2.c
    mv file2.s dist
```

It seems that this is happening because `make` does not know where the `.o` files are in it's environment.

With this a few questions:

- Can make have access to environment variables? If so, could you provide an example?
- Can make be made aware of incremental builds when distribution directory is different from current directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix your build you'll need to do something like this:

```
# Link to executable
result: dist/file1.o dist/file2.o
    gcc dist/file1.o dist/file2.o -o result

# Assemble to .o object files in main directory
dist/file1.o:    dist/file1.s
    gcc -c dist/file1.s -o dist/file1.o

dist/file2.o:    dist/file2.s
    gcc -c dist/file2.s -o dist/file2.o

# Compile to .s assembly files
dist/file1.s:    file1.c
    gcc -S file1.c -o dist/file1.s

dist/file2.s:    file2.c
    gcc -S file2.c -o dist/file2.s
```

You can certainly use environment variables in make too.. though I'm not sure how that relates to the core of your question: Just use something like this, set BUILDDIR and OBJDIR and have a makefile like this:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/foo : $(OBJDIR)/bar.o
   g++ $(OBJDIR)/bar.o -o $(BUILDDIR)/foo
```

Though you can make this  (and my fixed makefile too) nicer using [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

```
$(BUILDDIR)/foo : $(OBJDIR)/bar.o
  g++ $? -o $@
```

Comment: I think your answer is just fine. Even though 90% of the above makefile is redundant and can be replaced by an implicit rule.

%.o: %.c
    gcc $? -o $@

${BUILDIR}/foo: ${OBJDIR}/bar.o ${OBJDIR}/bar2.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

Comment: @Alex agreed the rules can be cleaned up a heap. And for real production use the dependencies should be being pulled out using makedepend or `gcc -MM` etc. But hopefully its enough to help JAM.

Comment: I didn't know both of these. (Normally I prefer generated Makefiles aka CMake or Automake)

Answer (score 1):

1,  You can access your environment variables like any other variable; eg, `$(TERM)`

2,   just change your make target to include the destination directory:

```
 dist/file1.o:    file1.s
      gcc -c dist/file1.s -o $@
```

Where `$@` is an implicit variable representing for the target, `dist/file1.o` in this example.